# Obtain B-S-M from a binomial tree as n goes to infinty using Lebesgue integral

Tags: black-scholes, binomial-tree, call, integral

My question is simple, consider a European call with payoff max(S_T-K, 0), Let's suppose that the underlying stock follows a binomial tree with up and down factors I know as we take n goes to infinity that the stock is log-normally distributed at time t=T (I know how to derive it). The idea is to derive the B-S-M pricing formula as the expected value of the present value of  max(S_t-K, 0) using the Lebesgue integral I write this like:
`$\int_{\Omega} max(S_T-K,0) dP$`
where P if I am not mistaken is the risk-neutral measure (since usually for a binomial tree we use the risk-neutral probabilities).
How can I  set P to compute this? Once I have a measure P finding the distribution of max(S_t-K, 0) and then compute its density is right way to continue?. Finally, doing this should I arrive B-S-M pricing formula for a call?